# How to close all windows of Mac OS X Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Having 30 or 40 windows of different folders open, is there any way to close all of them at once? I tried to relunch Finder, and I was happy for a second having no open window anymore, but it reopened all the folder windows again :-)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, you can use the shortcut <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: Holding down *Option* while clicking the close button also works

Comment: as an apple fanboy, you might automatically know the meaning of the hieroglyphics that describe the shortcut, but it might be helpful to mention the words option and command, for those who have not carved those symbols into their macbook. the command symbol was there, but the option one is not. "knowing" a symbol means something is all well and good, but the average user just looks at the keyboard and goes "duh? dont' see that key"

Comment: Another option, if you don't want to remember option-key shortcuts: Window > Merge All Windows, then close the single remaining window.

Answer (score 14):

A sidenote on this: Often such commands are not visible in the main menu if you just click it. However, if you press ⌥ *while the menu is open*, then the menu will change to view the alternate feature.

Another example:

**File** > **Get Info ⌘I**

[image: File menu without modifier keys pressed]

will turn into **File** > **Show Inspector ⌥⌘I**

[image: File menu with ⌥ key pressed]

once you press ⌥. As you can see in this image, **Close Window ⌘W** turns into **Close All Windows ⌥⌘W** as well.